# ReactNative: How to use useState with useMemo

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function with two parameters that returns an object(palette). The first parameter is the index for an object in palette and the second parameter controls whether to return the light or dark object.

```js
const Theme = (index:String, DarkMode:Boolean) => {

const palette = {

background:{
light,
dark,
},

custom:{
light,
dark,
},

}
 
return(palette[index][DarkMode]);
}
```

Then in my react component I use this function to style my element.

```js
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); // state
const bg = Theme("background",darkMode); // function

// then in my component style

backgroundColor:`${bg.background}`,
```

Then I have a button that toggle my darkmode state so that my theme function returns the light object instead of dark and vice versa, but the problem is the background-color of my component does not change even when the state does.

So my question is: "How do I use React.useMemo to recall my function and re-render my component when the state changes?".

Comment: Lookup React.Context and a theme provider example. This is not appropriate usage of useMemo.

Comment: @SamuelGoldenbaum I know I can achieve this using useContext and createContext but I was just exploring if there was a different way to achieve this. Also I'm just using useMemo and useEffect for the first time so I don't really understand what an appropriate usage of useMemo would be. I have checked the docs but it is just not clicking in my head.

Comment: Memoization is simply a way to cache results when you are given the same set of params (dependencies). Imagine a function that does a decent amount of computation or has to make external calls etc. If you are given the same set of params again, then you would rather avoid running the complete process again and rather return the result from the previous calculation.

Comment: useMemo is for when you want to memoize the returned value of a costly/expensive calculation

useCallBack is when you want to memoize the function itself (i.e. you pass is down as props and use it in the child's useEffect...per say)

I agree with Samuel, useContext would be the most ideal solution IMHO

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanation @SamuelGoldenbaum. I have looked up some videos on youtube about react hooks and I think I understand them better now.